# VS 2015 Data Breakpoints

Tags: visual-studio-2015, vs-community-edition

I am using VS 2015 Community to develop a MVC 5 website. A value, on which some functionality is dependent, inadvertently changes. So, instead of hours of tracing I decided to set a Data Breakpoint. 
This kind of breakpoints, however, are disabled (see the picture)

[image: Look at the Data Breakpoints... menu item]

Next one too...

[image: The Data Breakpoints is disabled here too...]

After some googling here and there it turned out that nothing in VS 2015 relates to Data Breakpoints (in prev. version Mixed Code Debugging enabled/disabled was mentioned but no such option in VS 2015, etc.).

Is it the "Community" edition to be blamed? Or something else?

Comment: Data breakpoints cannot work in a program that has a garbage collector that constantly moves the data around.  Just set a breakpoint on the property setter instead.  If this is a public field then you just discovered one more reason to favor properties.

Comment: Well, yes. System.Threading.CurrentThread.CurrentCultue. Thanks for the advice. And, BTW, when is it garbage-collected?

Comment: I have the same issue in Visual Studio 2017